# Pass a component with input from parent to child in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have created a custom tab component in react. It receives keys as tab headers and components as tabContent:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Tabs = ({ keys, tabContent }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState({
    key: keys[0],
    content: tabContent[0],
  });
  const handleTabChange = (e) => {
    if (e) {
      let keyIndex = keys.findIndex(function (o) {
        return o === e;
      });
      setActive({ key: keys[keyIndex], content: tabContent[keyIndex] });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {keys.map((key) => (
          <button
            className={`${
              key === active.key ? "tab-button-active" : "tab-button"
            }`}
            key={key}
            onClick={() => handleTabChange(key)}
          >
            {key}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="tab-content">{active.content}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Tabs;
```

I include this in my parent component as

```js
<Tabs keys={['Test1', 'Test2']} tabContent={[<TestComponent1 data={data}>, <TestComponent2 data={data}>]} />
```

This renders fine, but when `data` is changed in the parent through `useState`, the content of the `TestComponent`s are not updated dynamically. They change only if I switch tabs.

Is there a way to have them change dynamically? Also, I hope to use the tab component with other contents and thus would prefer to not pass `data` as input to tab component.

Also, I am new to React, is there a better approach to what I am trying to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue you're facing is due to the fact that the TestComponent1 and TestComponent2 instances are created once and not re-rendered when the parent component's state changes. You can use the React.memo to memoize the components, ensuring they only re-render when their props change.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried defining  `const Hist = useMemo(() => <Component1 data={data} />, [data])` and passed `Hist` to Tab component. But it didn't render at all.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try a variation of this where you pass in the data to the tabs and re nder the component with the data in the tabs component!

app.tsx

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';

import './style.css';
import Tabs from './tabs';
import { TestComponent1 } from './test1';
import { TestComponent2 } from './test2';

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('testy');
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setData('qwerty')}>qwerty</button>
      <Tabs
        keys={['Test1', 'Test2']}
        data={data}
        tabContent={[TestComponent1, TestComponent2]}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

tabs.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Tabs = ({ keys, tabContent, data }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState({
    key: keys[0],
    content: tabContent[0],
  });
  const handleTabChange = (e) => {
    if (e) {
      let keyIndex = keys.findIndex(function (o) {
        return o === e;
      });
      setActive({ key: keys[keyIndex], content: tabContent[keyIndex] });
    }
  };
  const TabRef = active.content;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {keys.map((key) => (
          <button
            className={`${
              key === active.key ? 'tab-button-active' : 'tab-button'
            }`}
            key={key}
            onClick={() => handleTabChange(key)}
          >
            {key}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="tab-content">
        <TabRef data={data} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Tabs;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ueynyc)

Comment: Thanks! I might end up going with this approach. I was hoping to reuse the tab component with other content as well.

Comment: I updated the question to mention that I would like to use the tab component with other content. Thus the preference is not to pass data if possible.